# C# Ini receive all Sections

Tags: c#, dll, kernel32

My code looks as follows.

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string filepath);

[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filepath);

[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileSection(string lpAppName, byte[] lpszReturnBuffer, int nSize, string lpFileName);

public string iniReadValue(string section, string key)
{
  StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
  GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
  return temp.ToString();
}
```

Now to my Problem:
I have a IniFile that contains different sections with multiple keys per section. In order to find the highest value of a specific key of all sections I need to retrieve all section names in order to access the keys and the value of the keys.

I tried by using:

```
GetPrivateProfileString(null, key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
```

as well as

```
ini.iniReadValue(null, key);
```

both of them only get me the first section and they don't touch the rest.

Is there any possibility to get all the Sectionnames into preferably a List?

Found the Solution for this Problem thanks to your comments:
I'll post it here for people to find:

```
        public ComboBox SectionNames()
        {
            ComboBox cboConfiguration = new ComboBox();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(buffer, buffer.Length, this.path);
            string allSections = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
            string[] sectionNames = allSections.Split('\0');
            foreach (string sectionName in sectionNames)
            {
                if (sectionName != string.Empty)
                cboConfiguration.Items.Add(sectionName);
            }
            // Returns All names as Items in Combobox
            return cboConfiguration;
        }
```

ofc with

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
            static extern int GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(byte[] lpszReturnBuffer, int nSize, string lpFileName);
```

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser . Disclaimer: no personal experience. But it has to be better than P/Invoking to functions that are only kept around for compatibility.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Why does it have to be better?

Comment: Please look at [GetPrivateProfileSectionNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724352(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: because P/Invoking is often (not always) slower than using pure managed code, is not portable, is easy to get wrong, and is difficult to debug when you do get it wrong. You're technically right in that a managed library doesn't *have* to be better, though. That's just an expression of hopefulness. I'd use the `*Profile*` functions only if I needed their odd backward compatibility quirks that couldn't (or shouldn't) be replicated in clean parsers.

Comment: *Anything* is better than GetPrivateProfileString().  Which is a truly screwed-up function due to its Win3 compatibility behavior.  Excessively slow because it opens and closes the file on every call (so 20-50 msec on a spindle drive), doesn't know anything about Unicode, looks in unexpected places.  Don't use it.

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as an answer, not as part of your question. Yes, you are allowed to answer your own questions.